# VBA code to copy range of data from closed file in SharePoint to open file

Tags: excel, vba

This question has been asked in different chats and I have tried to incorporate the varying solutions but without success.  I am attempting to open a SharePoint file and copy data from the file to the open file that has the macro within. The below solution is the last attempt I tried that did open the SharePoint file but would not select the desired range.  A Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range was returned.  If it makes it easier, my goal is to simply copy the entire sheet from the closed file into the open file.  Code used is below.  Any direction and or suggestions are appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("http://employee.xtra.net/sites/Ops/Support%20Launch%20Docs/ep_timing_wb_report.xlsx")
Set y = ThisWorkbook

x.Sheets("ep_timing_wb_report 1").Range("A:AA").Copy
y.Sheets("ep_timing_wb_report").Range("A:AA").PasteSpecial

x.close

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you open Excel files like that via Hyperlinks? As a quick test, save that locally, update the path with the local path, and see if it works.

Comment: Yes Hyperlinks do work to open the desired file.   Because many people will be looking at the data and often, I would really like to have a macro perform the update without having to open copy and paste.  My error is when x.Sheets attempts to .copy.  The Run-time error results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bruce was correct with the recommendation of simply using a Hyperlink in the cell.  This was attempted earlier but I must not have linked properly.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you (comments included).

```
Sub OpenAndCloseWBFromSharePointFolder()

'If nobody has the file checked out
If Workbooks.CanCheckOut("http://excel-pc:43231/Shared Documents/ExcelList.xlsb") = True Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open the file on the SharePoint server
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://excel-pc:43231/Shared Documents/ExcelList.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever

'Close the workbook
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Else
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open the File to check if you already have it checked out
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://excel-pc:43231/Shared Documents/ExcelList.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever

'See if doc can be checked in
If Application.Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").CanCheckIn Then

'Check In, Save and Close
Application.Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").CheckIn SaveChanges:=True, Comments:="Checked-In before Delete"

'Open the file again
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://excel-pc:43231/Shared Documents/ExcelList.xlsb"

'Close the workbook
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").Close
End If
End If

End Sub
```